# Is github coded using angularJS in the front-end

Tags: angularjs, github

Just really curious about this,is github coded using angularJS in the front-end? I've noticed that the pages almost never reload, just a bunch of behind the scene requests. It acts more of a web app than a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can see by yourself:

[image]

Angular.js is just a very good framework around javascript, whatever you can do with angular you can do with vanilla javascript or with other framework (but with more pain).

Comment: This is not quite accurate. Checking if a global exists is not a good test of whether a library is in use. Often sites will use a JavaScript build tool that doesn't expose globals, by wrapping everything in `(function() { ... })();`, which hides any vars inside from the window namespace. For example, I build a React.js website using [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and typing 'React' in the console comes up with exactly the same error.

Comment: A better idea would be to use the browser's dev tools to search through the page's Javascript sources for a reference to angular, and though that may still give false negatives, it will be more accurate. (Ctrl-Shift-F in the Chrome dev tools.)

Comment: @cormacrelf In general you are right, but in the case of Angular.js 1.x, it always has a global property.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have anything to do with this site, but I believe it serves your purpose:

http://builtwith.com/github.com

It allows you to enter any site, and it attempts to scrape production details for you.

Answer (score 1):

They use "PJAX" for the seamless transitions:

> pjax is a jQuery plugin that uses ajax and pushState to deliver a fast browsing experience with real permalinks, page titles, and a working back button.
>
> https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

(seems its now pjax2: https://github.com/github/pjax)

Github uses github so you can check out a lot of their libraries at https://github.com/github